# How to make docker to stop container when host process attached to tty terminates

Tags: docker

I'm running a docker containers interactively:

```
sudo docker run --rm -t -i CONTAINER_NAME bash
```

I need instances of containers to be purged after usage. Also container does not have any sense since tty is lost. When session is closed from container side (exit in bash) everything works fine but if my ssh session to host disconnects container stays running (shown in docker ps). This could also be reproduced by opening container in tmux window and then killing a window.

Is there a way to make docker to stop a container if host process (ssh session or tmux) that is attached to tty terminates?

Comment: use ssh with the `-t` option?